# Tensorflow on laptop with Integrated Intel® UHD Graphics 620 and eGPU with Nvidia GPU

Tags: tensorflow

In case I buy a Thinkpad with Integrated Intel® UHD Graphics 620 and install Ubuntu Linux and TensorFlow under it. Then, later on I add eGPU with Nvidia GPU. Should I install the GPU version of TensorFlow or non-GPU version or both on the laptop?

Answer (score 2):

You can start using the CPU Tensorflow version while you have only the Intel Graphics, then install the GPU Tensorflow version later on when you get the NVidia GPU.

Most Tensorflow programs will fall back to CPU when CUDA is not available, so you don't even need to modify the program's code, just upgrade to GPU Tensorflow and get the speed boost.

Comment: Thanks. In case I want to use the UHD Graphics 620 when I am on the go and an eGPU with Nvidia GPU at home or in office, what should I do? Which version of Tensorflow should I install? Do I need to install both versions? Will things get messed up doing so?

Comment: things won't get messy, all you need is to install tensorflow-gpu and cuda and cudann and you are all set.